# How can I get the name of the image from url?

Tags: php, curl

I have a small question; In PHP I have used curl to get data from an URL:

```
$url = "http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg";
```

With that I use `curl_getinfo()` which gave me an array:

```
Array
(
[url] => http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg
[content_type] => image/jpeg
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 496
[request_size] => 300
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 2.735
[namelookup_time] => 0.063
[connect_time] => 0.063
[pretransfer_time] => 0.063
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 34739
[speed_download] => 12701
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 34739
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 1.282
[redirect_time] => 0
)
```

How can I get the name of the image in the link `[url] => http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg` such as

```
[image_name] : example
[image_ex] : jpg
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Strictly that isn't the name of the image, though it is the name most browsers would give it if they saved it most of the time, because most entites on the web don't have names but it's likely to be a good choice. If the person in charge of prelovac.com had really wanted to set a name they'd have used the content-disposition header. While browsers are allowed to still ignore that, if you want to match what most users will see files saved as, then examine that first and only examine the URI's path-information if it's absent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#85196)

Comment: For those that don't get a working link from above, it's http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 9):

Sometime url has additional parameters appended to it. In such scenario we can remove the parameter section first and then we can use the PHP's inbuilt pathinfo() function to get the image name from the url.

```
$url = 'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/shutterstock_65560759.jpg?itok=b8HiA95H';
```

Check if the image url has parameters appended.

```
if (strpos($url, '?') !== false) {
    $t = explode('?',$url);
    $url = $t[0];            
}
```

The resulting url variable now contain

`http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/shutterstock_65560759.jpg`

Use the [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to retrieve the desired details.

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo($url);
echo $pathinfo['filename'].'.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
```

This will give shutterstock_65560759.jpg as output.

Comment: Try to add some explanation to improve the quality of your answer

Comment: @Sinha This is precisely what I've been looking for, thanks so much for this answer.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth, glad to know that helped you. :)

Answer (score 7):

consider the following is the image path
 $image_url='http://development/rwc/wp-content/themes/Irvine/images/attorney1.png';
from this url to get image name with extention use following function   basename();
look following code

code:

```
$image_url='http://development/rwc/wp-content/themes/Irvine/images/attorney1.png';
echo basename($image_url);
```

output: 
attorney1.png

Answer (score 4):

```
$url_arr = explode ('/', $arr['url']);
$ct = count($url_arr);
$name = $url_arr[$ct-1];
$name_div = explode('.', $name);
$ct_dot = count($name_div);
$img_type = $name_div[$ct_dot -1];

echo $name . "  " . $img_type;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$URL = urldecode('http://www.greenbiz.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/wide_large/Woman_HORIZ.jpg?sunny=20$mal+1');
$image_name = (stristr($URL,'?',true))?stristr($URL,'?',true):$URL;
$pos = strrpos($image_name,'/');
$image_name = substr($image_name,$pos+1);
$extension = stristr($image_name,'.');
if($extension == '.jpg' || $extension == '.png' || $extension == '.gif' || $extension == '.jpeg'){`enter code here`
print $image_name;
}
```

Comment: There are PHP functions that can do this in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/(?:.+\/)(.+\.(png|jpg|jepg))[?#]?.*$/`

Example:

```php
$examples = [
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_query.jpg?itok=b8HiA95H',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_hash.jpg#hghgh',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_query.jpg?',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_hash.jpg#',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_multydots.65560759.jpg',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/image.png',
    'http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/without_ext',   
    ];

foreach($examples as $example) {
    preg_match('/(?:.+\/)(.+\.(png|jpg|jepg))[?#]?.*$/', $example, $matches);
    
    if(isset($matches[1]) && $matches[1]) {
     echo "Url: {$example}, image name: {$matches[1]} \n";   
    } else {
        echo "Url: {$example} is not image url \n";   
    }
}
```

Printed:

```
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_query.jpg?itok=b8HiA95H, image name: with_query.jpg 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_hash.jpg#hghgh, image name: with_hash.jpg 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_query.jpg?, image name: with_query.jpg 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_hash.jpg#, image name: with_hash.jpg 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/with_multydots.65560759.jpg, image name: with_multydots.65560759.jpg 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/image.png, image name: image.png 
Url: http://images.fitnessmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/story/without_ext is not image url
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna to get file name from url ignoring uri params, you can try this:

```
$url = 'http://host/filename.ext?params';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$pathInfo = pathinfo($parsedUrl['path']);
print_r($pathInfo);
Array
(
    [dirname] => /
    [basename] => filename.ext
    [extension] => ext
    [filename] => filename
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$imagePath = 'http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg';

$imageName = get_basename($imagePath);

function get_basename($filename)
{
    return preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $imagePath);
}
```