# Laravel 4 get image from url

Tags: image, upload, laravel, laravel-4

OK so when I want to upload an image. I usually do something like:

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$destinationPath = 'whereEver';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

if( $uploadSuccess ) {
    // save the url
}
```

This works fine when the user uploads the image. But how do I save an image from an URL???

If I try something like:

```
$url = 'http://www.whereEver.com/some/image';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
```

and then:

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function move() on a non-object
```

So, how do I upload an image from a URL with laravel 4??

Amy help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this will help you a lot but you might want to look at the [Intervention Library](http://image.intervention.io/). It's originally intended to be used as an image manipulation library but it provides saving image from url:

```
$image = Image::make('http://someurl.com/image.jpg')->save('/path/saveAsImageName.jpg');
```

Comment: This package does the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
        $url = "http://example.com/123.jpg";
        $url_arr = explode ('/', $url);
        $ct = count($url_arr);
        $name = $url_arr[$ct-1];
        $name_div = explode('.', $name);
        $ct_dot = count($name_div);
        $img_type = $name_div[$ct_dot -1];

        $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/'.$name;
        file_put_contents($destinationPath, file_get_contents($url));
```

this will save the image to your /public/img, filename will be the original file name which is 123.jpg for the above case.

the get image name referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557070/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-image-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's Input::file method is only used when you upload files by POST request I think. The error you get is because file_get_contents doesn't return you laravel's class. And you don't have to use move() method or it's analog, because the file you get from url isn't uploaded to your tmp folder.

Instead, I think you should use [PHP upload an image file through url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743780/php-upload-an-image-file-through-url) what is described here.

Like:

```
// Your file
$file = 'http://....';

// Open the file to get existing content
$data = file_get_contents($file);

// New file
$new = '/var/www/uploads/';

// Write the contents back to a new file
file_put_contents($new, $data);
```

I can't check it right now but it seems like not a bad solution. Just get data from url and then save it whereever you want

Comment: $new has to be a filename, rather than a directory