# Laravel passing URL to get method

Tags: php, laravel, routes, query-string

```
http://localhost:8000/image/https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/443395572783800322/nXTuit5o.jpeg
```

i want to pass url to the route like this

ROute is like this

```
Route::get('/image/{url}','ImageController@uploadImageViaUrl');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of using this BAD practice**

```
http://localhost:8000/image/https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/443395572783800322/nXTuit5o.jpeg
```

**Consider to use**

```
http://localhost:8000/image?link=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/443395572783800322/nXTuit5o.jpeg
```

**In routes.php**

```
Route::get('/image','ImageController@uploadImageViaUrl');
```

**In that Controller you can get img url**

```
$img_link = request()->query('link');
```

Comment: ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class App\Http\Controllers\ImageContoller does not exist it is giving me ths error

Comment: @AniketKarne It's `ImageController` not `ImageContoller`. Make sure it exist in `App\Http\Controllers`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible like that, because basically youre extending the route with all the slashes in it. After the https part in your image url you have 5 more slashes which would give your route the following weird pattern:

```
Route::get('/image/{url}/{someting?!}/{someting?!}/{someting?!}/...', 'ImageController@uploadImageViaUrl');
```

Concider using POST requests for uploading images, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776291/laravel-4-get-image-from-url) post will help?